# What are the implications of the Symantec CA distrust for code signing certificates?

Tags: java, applet, code-signing, oracleforms, symantec

I think I have a good understanding of whats happening with the Symantec CA distrust itself and I also understand the implications Chrome/Firefox users accessing sites via SSL, but will the distrust impact code signing, specifically in Java?  I'm attempting to determine if I must re-sign and re-issue JAR files to all of our customers.  The application in question is a JAR file which is part of a legacy *Oracle Forms* application.

**Code-signing Certificate details**

*Root*

```
CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign\, Inc. - For authorized use only,
OU=VeriSign Trust Network,
O=VeriSign\, Inc.,
C=US
```

*Intermediate*

```
CN=Symantec Class 3 SHA256 Code Signing CA,
OU=Symantec Trust Network,
O=Symantec Corporation,
C=US
```

*Specific Questions*

1. Are certs from the aforementioned intermediate/root CA affected by the distrust?
2. Is it true that Java's CA blacklist would have to be manually updated for this to affect an installation of Java that preexisted the distrust decision?
3. Is Java going to update their blacklist to include the Symantec CA's which Chrome/Firefox are distrusting in future releases of Java?  I can't find any mention of this one way or the other.

Comment: Related: SecuritySO: [*Symantec rooted certificates trust and Oracle Java trust store, is Oracle planing to remove trust as well?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182899/symantec-rooted-certificates-trust-and-oracle-java-trust-store-is-oracle-planin)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff Your comment is indefinite loop